# UnCaught Exception and Unhandled Promise Rejections

Tags: node.js, express

What is the difference between UnCaught Exception and Unhandled Promise Rejections in nodejs.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`Uncaught Exception` is when you `throw` an error and did not catch anywhere.

`Unhandled promise rejection` is similar, when you fail to catch a `Promise.reject`.

It's about whether the error was generated by `throw` or by `Promise.reject` (more like `error` generate from `sync` vs `async` process/code). Note that `throw` inside an `async` function is `Promise.reject` as `async` functions are wrapped inside `Promise` for you

Read more about [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: Thanks for the best explaining